# Python - use a list of names to find exact match in the free text pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, string, pattern-matching

I have an Excel file containing a free-form text column (that sometimes is structured like an email), where I need to **find all first and last names, phone numbers and emails and add extra columns saying TRUE/FALSE** to these fields. I do not need to extract matched data (i.e. note it down in an adjacent column), although that could be an advantage.

**NB**: I do not know the names, phones or emails that I need to find, so it is pure guesswork. I have a list of registered first names with 40k+ entries, as well as a list of most common last names with another few hundred entries. For phone numbers and emails I used **regex**. Phones can be structured like (but will never start with 0):

- +45 0000 0000
- +45 00000000
- 00 00 00 00
- 0000 0000
- 00000000
- 0000-0000

So far, I managed to filter out roughly 10000 rows out out ~20000 row file, although my solution contains a lot of false positives. Fx my regex extracts a lot of sample/project numbers (e.g. D03121110002 or I08133100006 or 835-2019-8066115 or 835-2019-80745616). Project numbers always start with D or I and are followed by 0.... Is there maybe a way to filter out numbers that start with 0? Whereas sample numbers contain at least 2 "-" within them (phone numbers should have only 1 "-" separating 4 digits on each side).

What is more, some column rows marked TRUE for first names, contain text like "**Det er OK.**", where Python (I assume) combines the entire text together and extracts any matching substing to a name from a list, in this case I guess that could be "**t er O**" or "**r OK**", since my list has names "**Tero**" and "**Rok**" (although the case does not match and it combines letters from 2/3 separate words, which is not what I want)... Weirdly enough, this is NOT TRUE for the same text written in lowercase and without "**.**" at the end, i.e. "**det er ok**", which is marked as FALSE! P.S. there are unfortunatelly few names in the emails that are written in lowercase letters and not sentence case as it should be...

**Sample email** (with names Thomas, Lars, Ole, Per):

```
Hej Thomas,

De 24 timer var en af mange sager som vi havde med til møde med Lars og Ole. De har godkendt den under dette møde.

Mvh. Per
```

**Below is my code.**

```
# Import datasets and create lists/variables
import pandas as pd
import re
from pandas import ExcelWriter

namesdf = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', sheet_name='Alle Navne')
names = list(namesdf['Names'])

lastnamesdf = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', sheet_name='Frie Efternavne')
lastnames = list(lastnamesdf['Frie Efternavne'])

reg = re.compile("\d{2}[\s]??\d{2}[-\s]??\d{2}[\s]??\d{2}|\(\d{2}\)\s*\d{2}[-\s]??\d{2}[\s]??\d{2}|[\W?\w+]@[\w.-]+")


# Import dataset and drop NULLS
df = pd.read_excel(r'Entreprise Beskeder.xlsx', sheet_name='dataark')
df["Besked"].dropna(inplace = True)


# Compare dataset to the created lists/variables to match names, phone numbers and emails
df["Navner"] = df["Besked"].str.contains("|".join(names)) # Creates new column and adds TRUE/FALSE for first names
df["Efternavner"] = df["Besked"].str.contains("|".join(lastnames)) # Creates new column and adds TRUE/FALSE for last names
df["Mobil|Email"] = df["Besked"].str.contains(reg) # Creates new column and adds TRUE/FALSE for phones/emails


# Save the result
writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

**I would appreciate any suggestions that could potentially improve my code** and reduce manual work that it will take to filter out all of these false positive cells that I found! Thanks :)

Comment: `\w+@[\w.-]+` is really poor for email, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although that seems extremely complex... Since my file does not contain that many emails (especially with varying formats), I can easily capture all of them with `[\W?\w+]@[\w.-]+`, so I think I will stick to the basic form in this case, as it is also much easier to understand :)

Comment: `[\W?\w+]` matches **1** character in the list: `non word character`, `?`, `word character` or `+`, your regex matches, for example, `?@-` or `@@.` not sure these are valid emails!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the regex part, I would suggest the following `(^|\s|\+45)\s?((\d{2})([\-\s])(\d{2})\4(\d{2})\4(\d{2})|\d{4}[\s\-]?\d{4})`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/unz6Ke/9

```
Matching strings
================
plop +45 00 00 00 00 some words
plop +45 0000 0000 some words
plop +45 00000000 some words
plop +4500000000 some words
plop 00 00 00 00 some words
plop 0000 0000 some words
plop 0000-0000 some words
plop 00000000 some words
plop 00-00-00-00 some words

Unwanted strings
================
plop 15.10.2019 some words
plop 04-10-2017 some words
plop 27/9-18 some words
plop D03121110002 some words
plop 835-2019-8066115 some words
```

**Some details:**

`(^|\s|\+45)` matching start of line, space or +45

`(\d{2})([\-\s])(\d{2})\4(\d{2})\4(\d{2})` matching 4 couple of 2 digits separated by a   (space) or `-`

`\d{4}[\s\-]?\d{4}` matching 2 groups of 4 digits separated by a   (space) or `-`

**Edit**: improving the regex to catch the phone numbers inside text and removing useless usage of character classes.

Comment: Why are you putting `\d` in a character class?

Comment: The given code only works when phone numbers are separated from the text. However, once I enclose numbers somewhere within an email (or within a text), the code does not find anything. Any solution to that? Also, I forgot to mention that some numbers can have a following separation: 0000-0000.... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for help, it was a useful tip on fixing regex!